# Python random.seed() without system time

Tags: python, random, time

I am making a game for a [Thumby](https://thumby.us) in Python. I am using the `random` library to generate a random y value for a sprite. The `random.seed()` value, if left untouched, uses the system time. The Thumby doesn't have a system time, so how would I go about generating a random number?

So far I have tried having a value constantly go up by 0.001 in the `while true` loop, then setting that as the seed every time the level is reset. That is not working too well, so I need some advice.

Edit: Ok it sounds too good to be true, but I just went to check it again, and it works. I don't know how or why, but it fixed itself.

Comment: Just out of curiosity. What happens if you do nothing and ignore seed(). Do you get the same random numbers each time? Perhaps the implementers already took care of this.

Comment: Yes, I get the same random sequence every time

Comment: Have you tried seeding with the output from `os.urandom()`? That *should* produce the best possible random for the platform, and you can use 4 or 8 bytes of it as the argument to `random.seed()`. Also, take a look at `machine.rng()` (if it exists) and see if that produces something unpredictable.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/random.html#random.seed), that should be the behavior when calling `random.seed()` without arguments: _When no argument (or None) is passed in it will (if supported by the port) initialise the PRNG with a true random number (usually a hardware generated random number)._

Answer (score 2):

For a pseudo-random generator, you don't need a seed for *every* random number, just for the initial seed value. After that, the PRNG algorithm takes over.

So, if you're forced to start with the same seed every time you run the game, you need to introduce some *other* source of randomness to set the seed.

*One* method would be to use the fact that user input is rarely consistent. You can take advantage of that by generating and throwing away random numbers periodically while waiting for the player to start the game with a keypress, something like:

```py
def wait_for_user_start()
    thumby.display.drawText("Press button A", 0, 0, 1)
    while not thumby.buttonA.pressed():
        _ = random.randint()
```

That way, unless your user is *incredibly* consistent in how quickly they press the button, you'll have a different starting point in the PRNG sequence.

---

You could even make it less likely that the user can fudge things by holding buttons down so the function exits immediately. Note that this code is written without the benefit of full testing but you should hopefully get the general idea from the comments:

```py
import thumby as th

# All buttons to make things easier.

BUTTONS = [th.buttonA, th.buttonB, th.buttonC, th.buttonD]
TEXTS = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

# Waits until no buttons are pressed.

def wait_no_buttons_pressed():
    # Continuously randomises until no buttons are pressed.

    th.display.drawText("Release all buttons", 0, 0, 1)
    while any([btn.pressed() for btn in BUTTONS]):
        _ = random.random()

    # Returns random button to check in next stage.

    selector = random.randint(0, 3)
    return (BUTTONS[selector], TEXTS[selector])

# Waits for a specific button to be the only one pressed.

def wait_for_only_button_x(button, text):
    # Inform user as to which button is needed and start checking.

    th.display.drawText("Press button " + text, 0, 0, 1)
    ok = False
    while not ok:
        # Randomise until desired button on and all others off.

        _ = random.random()
        ok = button.pressed()
        for test_button in BUTTONS:
            if test_button is not button:
                ok = ok and not test_button.pressed()

# Randomises until correct button sequence complete.

def wait_for_user_start():
    # Press sequence is none, A, none, random, none.

    _ = wait_no_buttons_pressed()
    wait_for_only_button_x(th.buttonA, "A")
    button, text = wait_no_buttons_pressed()
    wait_for_only_button_x(button, text)
    _ = wait_no_buttons_pressed()
```

Comment: I am so confused. That obviously works in any other scenario, but for some reason, I am always getting the same set of values, no matter how long or short I wait before starting.

Comment: Ok it sounds too good to be true, but I just went to check it again, and it works. I don't know how or why, but it fixed itself. I am still confused btw

Comment: To explain why 'it fixed itself': It's possible you were using the Thumby emulator which will produce the same sequence if doing seed() or not seeding, but will work to giv different numbers on Thumby hardware.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, you can still use time-related functions to set the seed. The microcontroller powering the Thumby is a [Raspberry Pi RP2040](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/microcontrollers/rp2040.html), which has an RTC (Real Time Clock). You can access the [RTC from MicroPython](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/machine.RTC.html#class-rtc-real-time-clock) and use it as your seed, even if the time it returns isn't the correct current time.

Comment: I didn't know that. So the RTC runs off power, or boot time? I will set the seed to the RTC as shown in the link you posted and see if it works.

Comment: So it's not working at all. I am really confused because when I printed the values twice, five seconds apart, it showed the correct values with the second value increasing by five. I think it might be a problem with the Thumby firmware or micropython

Comment: Ok it sounds too good to be true, but I just went to check it again, and it works. I don't know how or why, but it fixed itself.